# force:outputField does not generate in dynamic component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dynamiccomponent

I'm trying to use force:outputField in dynamic generate component and it does not work. When I place console.log messages, I do not see any message in console.

My code is

```
$A.createComponent(componentType, {
                    'aura:id': fieldName,
                    'value' : accountObj[fieldName]?accountObj[fieldName]:''
                    },
                    function(outputelement, status, error){
                       if(status == 'SUCCESS'){
                          $A.createComponent('div', 
                          { class: 'slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--1-of-2'}, 
                                                              function(forceElement, forceStatus, error){
    if(forceStatus == 'SUCCESS'){
         var forceBody = forceElement.get('v.body');
                                                       forceBody.push(outputelement);
                                                                      forceElement.set('v.body', forceBody);
          var body = container.get('v.body');
                                                                      body.push(forceElement);
                                                                      container.set('v.body', body);
                                                                      console.log(container.get('v.body'));
     }else{
                                                                      console.log(error);
                                                                      console.log(wrapStatus);
     }
    }
   );
  }
 }
);
```

In which componentType am passing as force:outputField and values from accountobj[fieldName]. It works for all other elements such as lightning:input, lightning:select, etc.

Can you please help?